# Export multiple csv files containing only rows containing same ID values from original dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, csv

I'm wanting to create separate dataframes taken from a csv file, and each row with the same ID to a new dataframe (or csv file)... the list of IDs would be unknown unless I open the csv file which contains thousands of IDs... I don't necessarily need separate dataframes for each ID but I do need separate csv files for each ID... the csv could be named after the batch and saved in the same file path as the df1 source.

df1source:
ID      A      B
0  B345    male   12
1  B980  female   34
2  B980  female   44
3  B345  female   04
4  B456    male   78

import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv(r"C:file\path\df1source.csv")

desired output:

df2 =
ID      A      B
0  B345    male   12
1  B345  female   04

df3 =
ID      A      B
0  B980  female   34
1  B980  female   44

df4 =
ID      A      B
0  B456    male   78

Comment: Display your code properly

Answer (score 0):

You can mask your DataFrame similar to numpy. `mask = df['<column>']==<value>` or `mask = df.<column>==<value>` and mask your DataFrame with `df[mask]`

## Example

```py
import pandas as pd

l = 10
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': np.arange(l)%4,  # %4 to get 4 IDs
                   'y': np.random.random(l)})

df_id_list = []
for i in df.ID.unique():
    df_id_list.append(df[df.ID==i])
    
df_id_list[0]
```

|  | ID | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 | 4 |
| 8 | 0 | 8 |

## Alternative if IDs are unique anyhow

If your IDs are anyhow unique, there is probably no need to split the DataFrame into the IDs. Each ID is represented by a row of the DataFrame i.e. a `pd.Series`. To get access to a row by ID you can set the ID column as index.

```py
l = 10
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': np.arange(l)**2, 'y': np.arange(l)})
df.set_index("ID", inplace=True)

df.loc[9].y
# 3
```